# Channel Frequency Number

Tags: c, linux

I have written the code for printing information about network interface such as "name", "address", "net mask", "MAC address".

But I want to add "channel frequency" for wlan0 to my code and print this info, but I do not know what should I do.

This is my code:

```
int wlan(){

     struct ifreq ifr;
        int sock, j, k;
        char *p, addr[32], mask[32], mac[32];

        sock=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (-1==sock) {
            perror("socket() ");
            return 1;
        }    

        strncpy(ifr.ifr_name,"wlan0",sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)-1);
        ifr.ifr_name[sizeof(ifr.ifr_name)-1]='\0';  

        if (-1==ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr)) {
            perror("ioctl(SIOCGIFADDR) ");
            return 1;
        }
        p=inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)(&ifr.ifr_addr))->sin_addr);
        strncpy(addr,p,sizeof(addr)-1);
        addr[sizeof(addr)-1]='\0';

        if (-1==ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFNETMASK, &ifr)) {
            perror("ioctl(SIOCGIFNETMASK) ");
            return 1;
        }
        p=inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)(&ifr.ifr_netmask))->sin_addr);
        strncpy(mask,p,sizeof(mask)-1);
        mask[sizeof(mask)-1]='\0';

        if (-1==ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr)) {
            perror("ioctl(SIOCGIFHWADDR) ");
            return 1;
        }
        for (j=0, k=0; j<6; j++) {
            k+=snprintf(mac+k, sizeof(mac)-k-1, j ? ":%02X" : "%02X",
                (int)(unsigned int)(unsigned char)ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[j]);
        }
        mac[sizeof(mac)-1]='\0';

        printf("\n");
        printf("name:    %s\n",ifr.ifr_name);
        printf("address: %s\n",addr);
        printf("netmask: %s\n",mask);
        printf("macaddr: %s\n",mac);
        printf("\n");

        close(sock);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know the channel currently in use, or the list of channels supported by the interface?  Can you see the relevant information by running `iwlist frequency`?

Comment: i can see this channel number by using Iwlist in the terminal of linux.

Comment: What does `iwconfig wlan0` show?  Is the info you want in there?

Comment: I can see this info by using iwlist.
i want to get this channel number and print it.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be so kind as to paste the output of iwlist into your question, with a note on exactly which piece of info you want from it.  From there, you or someone else can probably dig into the iwlist source code and figure this out--I imagine it's written in C already.

Comment: you mean that I can not use ioctl function to get and print it?

Comment: Maybe you can.  Once you tell us exactly which field in the output of iwlist shows what you want, then digging into the code of iwlist (which is available) should reveal a suitable method.

Answer (score 0):

Try the ioctl() command SIOCGIWFREQ.  It's mentioned here:
http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/wireless.h?v=2.6.11.8

Comment: But i do Not know how can i use this function for printing channel number in my code.